# Not able to update recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase with recyclerview and when I delete an item using a button it does delete within the firebase database but it doubles the data within the recyclerview .

code to show data:

```
public class testextends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Name;
    Button Button;
    private List<Task> allTask;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.task_list);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        allTask = new ArrayList<Task>();

        test= findViewById(R.id.test);
        but= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test");

       reference .addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                getAllTask(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }

        });

       }

    private void getAllTask(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String taskTitle = (String) singleSnapshot.child("test").getValue();

            allTask.add(new Task(taskTitle));
            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(BusinessManageCounters.this, allTask);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }
    }

    private void taskDeletion(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String taskTitle = (String) singleSnapshot.child("test").getValue();
            for(int i = 0; i < allTask.size(); i++){
                if(allTask.get(i).getTask().equals(taskTitle)){
                    allTask.remove(i);
                }
            }

            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(BusinessManageCounters.this, allTask);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there any other code needed to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your data change and event callback occurs, you are adding whole list in allTask.
But you forgot to remove old objects from list:

add one line in this method and check: `allTask.clear();`

```
private void getAllTask(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    allTask.clear();
    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String taskTitle = (String) singleSnapshot.child("counterName").getValue();
        if(taskTitle != null){
        allTask.add(new Task(taskTitle));
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(BusinessManageCounters.this, allTask);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }}
}
```

You also have to move following two line out of for loop:

```
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(BusinessManageCounters.this, allTask);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
```

and make:

```
private void getAllTask(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        allTask.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            String taskTitle = (String) singleSnapshot.child("counterName").getValue();
            if(taskTitle != null){
            allTask.add(new Task(taskTitle));
        }}
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(BusinessManageCounters.this, allTask);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have deletion code in onCreate() method so you need to make a configuration change(i.e change rotation of device) or kill app from recents screen and open it again, to notice the data has deleted, Generally what you do here about putting business logic into activity is very bad practice, you have many other options that will solve your problem and make your code cleaner, one of them:

-create a viewmodel and move the logic to it, then make your list a LiveData object so it become lifecycle aware and update UI immediately

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the previous answer, I want to recommend you to use ListAdapter instead of RecyclerViewAdapter